# Get the value of selected items in dynamically created dropdownlist into an array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, arrays, linq

I have two dropdownlists namely ddlCountry and ddlState. I am using jquery clone() method to create dynamic dropdownlist controls of the ddlCountry and ddlState dropdownlists.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="ddlPanel" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnClone" Text="Clone" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Cateogry:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryList" runat="server" class="ddlCountryClass"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>SubCategory:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateList" runat="server" class="ddlStateClass"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="target">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="target2">
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get Values" OnClick="GetDropDownListValues" />           

    </asp:Panel>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnClone]").bind("click", function () {
            var index = $("#target select").length + 1;
            //Clone the DropDownList
            var ddl = $("[id$=ddlCountryList]").clone(true);
            //Set the ID and Name
            ddl.attr("id", "ddlCountryList_" + index);
            ddl.attr("name", "ddlCountryList_" + index);
            ddl.append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Country</option>');
            //[OPTIONAL] Copy the selected value
            var selectedValue = $("[id$=ddlCountryList] option:selected").val();
            ddl.find("option[value = '" + selectedValue + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
            //Append to the DIV.
            $("#target").append(ddl);
            $("#target").append("<br /><br />");
            return false;
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnClone]").bind("click", function () {
            var index = $("#target2 select").length + 1;
            var ddl = $("[id$=ddlStateList]").clone();
            ddl.attr("id", "ddlStateList_" + index);
            ddl.attr("name", "ddlStateList_" + index);
            var selectedValue = $("[id$=ddlStateList] option:selected").val();
            ddl.find("option[value = '" + selectedValue + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#target2").append(ddl);
            $("#target2").append("<br /><br />");
            return false;
        });
    });
    //  Make Ajax call to fetch the state values.
    $(function () {

        $('#ddlStateList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#ddlStateList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#ddlStateList').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select State</option>');
        $('#ddlCountryList').change(function () {
            var $countryDropdown = $(this); // "this" is the event source
            var country = $countryDropdown.val();
            // Figure out the index of the country dropdown
            var index = $countryDropdown.attr('id').split("_")[1] || "";
            if (index) {
                index = "_" + index;
            }
            var $stateDropdown = $("#ddlStateList" + index);
            $stateDropdown.removeAttr("disabled");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/BindStates",
                data: "{'country':'" + country + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var j = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    var options;
                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>'
                    }

                    $stateDropdown.html(options)
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Something Went Wrong')
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to store the selected value of each in the country dropdownlists(not of ddlstate) such as ddlCountry,ddlcountry_1,ddlcountry_2 and so on....in an array.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle with minimum code to demonstrate your need, that would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, the dropdownlists are asp.net controls. so i am not sure if they are going to work on jsfiddle or not. I tried to copy this fiddle in there but it did not work. But here it is, it will create dropdownlists based on a button click with id incrementing by one and make ajax calls from country ddl to statedll(we can forget this part). I could ofcourse loop through it but there is another dropdownlist of state type. So how do i store the values of County type in an array?

Comment: Try making the `ClientIDMode = "Static"`. And then '$("#ddlCountryList option:selected").val()' will give you selected values. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i < somecounter; i++){
  string ddlCountry = "ddlcountry_" + i;
  DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ddlPanel.FindControl(ddlCountry);
  string value = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();

}
```

you have to put some counter and every time you add new dropdownlist increase the counter by one. Then you have the number of the dynamically created dropdownlists